# Service layer is it necessary?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Is it really necessary to implement a service layer? In my project it seems to have no benefit.

```
public void save(Student student) {
    StudentDao.save(student);
}
```

All it does is call the DAO layer:

```
public void save(Student student) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);
}
```

And this is the same thing for all my methods which call DAO layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is definitely not necessary to introduce an additional layer that brings you no benefit.

If your application has only simple CRUD functionality, you may never have the need for an extra service layer since the only provided service is persistence, which is already encapsulated in an own layer.

If your application starts to grow and you see yourself packing more functionality where it does not belong, e.g. view or persistence level code, then you can reconsider introducing a separate layer for it.

EDIT. You probably do need an extra service layer when you actually process the data after user input, before persisting etc.

An example would be a customer entering payment information. You would need to validate that information with the appropriate payment provider. Such functionality is typical for the service layer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary, but this is good place to enable transactions for method which calls many DAOs.

With service layer you can also separate service logic from DAO layer.